# Razor page with real-time price data using SSE

Tags: c#, html, ajax, razor, server-sent-events

I am trying to create a `Razor` page within my so-called "Server" solution to display some real-time stock prices, using the `server-sent event` approach. In the end, I am not getting any auto-refresh on the page and I do not know which part I am missing.

I start with the general price model called "Quotes" defined in "Quotes.cs":

```
namespace Server.Models
{
    public class Quotes
    {
        public double Bid { get; set; }
        public double Ask { get; set; }
        public double Last { get; set; }
        public string Timestamp { get; set; }

        public Quotes() 
        {
            this.Timestamp = String.Empty;
        }

        public Quotes(double bid, double ask, double last)
        {
            this.Bid = bid;
            this.Ask = ask;
            this.Last = last;
            this.Timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I have a hard-coded dictionary of stocks (for the sake of this example) that is defined in "Data.cs":

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

namespace Server.Models
{
    public class Data
    {
        public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, Quotes> DataDict { get; set; } = LoadData();

        public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, Quotes> LoadData()
        {
            ConcurrentDictionary < string, Quotes> dataDict = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Quotes>();
            dataDict.TryAdd("AAPL", new Quotes(188.0, 189.0, 186.0));
            dataDict.TryAdd("AMZN", new Quotes(158.0, 159.0, 156.0));
            dataDict.TryAdd("GOOG", new Quotes(140.0, 142.0, 144.0));
            dataDict.TryAdd("MSFT", new Quotes(410.0, 412.0, 411.0));
            dataDict.TryAdd("NFLX", new Quotes(550.0, 552.0, 554.0));
            return dataDict;
        }
    }
}
```

I use this dictionary both in the page and the service. The service is defined in "StocksService.cs", where I randomly move the prices (for the sake of the example):

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using Lib.AspNetCore.ServerSentEvents;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Server.Models;

namespace Server.Services
{
    public class StocksService : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly IServerSentEventsService _service;

        public StocksService(IServerSentEventsService service)
        {
            this._service = service;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            while(!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                IReadOnlyCollection<IServerSentEventsClient> clients = _service.GetClients();
                if (clients.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var (id, quotes) in Data.DataDict)
                    {
                        Random rand = new Random();
                        quotes.Bid += rand.Next(-1, 1);
                        quotes.Ask += rand.Next(-1, 1);
                        quotes.Last += rand.Next(-1, 1);
                        quotes.Timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();

                        var update = new
                        {
                            Id = id,
                            Bid = quotes.Bid,
                            Ask = quotes.Ask,
                            Last = quotes.Last,
                            Timestamp = quotes.Timestamp
                        };

                        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(update);

                        ServerSentEvent data = new ServerSentEvent
                        {
                            Id = "stock-update",
                            Type = "stock-update",
                            Data = new List<string>() { json },
                        };

                        await _service.SendEventAsync(data, cancellationToken);
                    }

                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), cancellationToken);
                }
            }
        }

        public override Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

In the page model, called "StocksModel.cshtml.cs", the dictionary of stocks is used as an attribute to allow its display.

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Server.Models;

namespace Server.Pages
{
    public class StocksModel : PageModel
    {
        public ConcurrentDictionary<string, Quotes> StocksDict { get; set; }

        public StocksModel()
        {
            StocksDict = Data.DataDict;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, the 'Razor' page "StocksModel.cshtml" is built:

```
@page
@model StocksModel
@{
}
<h1>Stock Quotes</h1>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr style="text-align:center">
            <th style="width:20%">Code</th>
            <th style="width:20%">Bid</th>
            <th style="width:20%">Ask</th>
            <th style="width:20%">Last</th>
            <th style="width:20%">Timestamp</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var (id, quotes) in Model.StocksDict)
        {
            <tr style="text-align:right">
                <td style="text-align:left">@id</td>
                <td id="bid_@id">@quotes.Bid</td>
                <td id="ask_@id">@quotes.Ask</td>
                <td id="last_@id">@quotes.Last</td>
                <td id="timestamp_@id">@quotes.Timestamp</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>

    const eventSource = new EventSource("/stocks-stream")

    eventSource.addEventListener("stock-update", function (event) {
        const stockData = JSON.parse(event.data);
        updateTable(stockData);
    };

    function updateTable(stockData) {
        document.getElementById('bid_$(id)') = stockData.bid;
        document.getElementById('ask_$(id)') = stockData.ask;
        document.getElementById('last_$(id)') = stockData.last;
        document.getElementById('timestamp_$(id)') = stockData.timestamp;
    }

</script>
```

To allow this to work, I have added to the "Program.cs" file the following dependency injections:

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<Data>();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
builder.Services.AddServerSentEvents();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IServerSentEventsService, ServerSentEventsService>();
app.MapServerSentEvents("/stocks-stream");
```

This gives as the complete "Program.cs" file:

```
using Lib.AspNetCore.ServerSentEvents;
using Server.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<Data>();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
builder.Services.AddServerSentEvents();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IServerSentEventsService, ServerSentEventsService>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.MapServerSentEvents("/stocks-stream");

app.Run();
```

Comment: Why not just use [Blazor - InteractiveServer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0) which uses SignalR (which [uses WebSockets, and SSE as a fallback under the covers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr#transport-selection-process)) to do this instead of using Server Sent Events directly? Since .NET 8 it does have this Fullstack capability and also supports just MVC style server-side rendering as well as streaming rendering and more. Or just SignalR. It's easier/ faster.

Comment: FYI: If you use just SignalR (without Blazor), there is a [JavaScript Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client) too.

Comment: @Mushroomator: Thank you for the tips. I am actually not familiar with `Blazor`. As for `SignalR`, I only expect a one-way stream hence my choice for `SSE`.